# VTK can not create its own map vtk.vtkDataSetMapper - Python

Tags: python, paraview

There is here such code.

```
import vtk
file_name = "1.vtk"
reader = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName(file_name)
reader.Update()  # Needed because of GetScalarRange
output = reader.GetOutput()
scalar_range = output.GetScalarRange()
lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()

mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:
    mapper.SetInput(output)
else:
    mapper.SetInputData(output)

mapper.SetScalarRange(scalar_range )
mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)

print(mapper)
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

scalar_bar = vtk.vtkScalarBarActor()
scalar_bar.SetLookupTable(lut)
scalar_bar.SetTitle(u'AS1_X\nARM')

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
renderer.AddActor2D(scalar_bar)
render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
render_window.SetSize(800, 600)

interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)
interactor.Initialize()
render_window.Render()
interactor.Start()
```

He gives this picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgsWP.png
But I do not like such a map, I need to get this card ...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nochv.png
I also would like to sign the values in the scalar bar.
In principle, I do all this with the help of Paraview, but there it must be fairly hands on it, I would like to automatically create everything.

Comment: your code is vtkPython code, where are you executing it in ParaView ?

Comment: I'm not doing it in Paraview. I'm getting the required image in Paraview, but I want to do it programmatically without Paraview . 
I was able to do
lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
lut.SetNumberOfTableValues(6)
now I have 6 values in scalar_bar
https://yadi.sk/i/6j1u3LiI3Ywo5Q

Comment: So you are using paraview to open a dataset ? how do you get the image in paraview ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I'm not explaining it well.
In Paraview, I got results, but I want to make my program on vtk.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I'm not explaining it well.
In Paraview, I got results, but I want to make my program on vtk.
I added
`code`
lut.SetNumberOfTableValues(6)

and

bcf = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
bcf.SetInputData(output)
# Use either the minimum or maximum value
bcf.SetValue(0, 0.05)
bcf.SetValue(1, 0.15)
bcf.SetValue(2, 0.25)
bcf.SetValue(3, 0.45)
bcf.SetValue(4, 0.55)
`code`

The result is already good, but now you need to make sure that there is a fill.
Here's what happened https://yadi.sk/i/xlFVT9fQ3YxJJf
Here's what I want to get  https://yadi.sk/i/5lcVL1hA3YxJT9

Comment: Thanks to all, I found how to do C ++
https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VisualizationAlgorithms/FilledContours

Comment: Please close this thread then, for example by answering your own question.